# Mailchimp update from mailchimp to mysql

Tags: mysql, synchronization, mailchimp

I'm currently trying to implement mailchimp to keep my mysql database and mailchimp subscribers list synced.
I'm using this library: https://github.com/drewm/mailchimp-api/ and from mysql to mailchimp, everything works fine, but I'm wondering how I can do the reverse operation: update from mailchimp to my site.

Thanks for your help ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the MailChimp webhooks.  When something interesting happens in Mailchimp, they will send a POST request to a url that you specify (via the admin controls in Mailchimp, or an API call), with information about whatever it was that happened.

The Mailchimp docs about this are: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/

I don't know of any libraries that could help with this at your end, I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks Matt for your reply ;)
Ok, i though it's something that could be done with the API v2!! I found this sample script: https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/webhooks/downloads/#php I'll have a deep look into that very soon and keep you posted

Comment: well, it looks like everything works fine, I had to use PHP curl to update my database ;)
Thanks for the initial tip ;)